# Finding the type of a Tk widget

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Is there a way to know what is the "type" of a Tk widget?

As an example, let's suppose I create a label, using the `tk::label` command or the `ttk::label` command.

After that, I just have the path name of the widget, for example `.l`. Now, I'd like to know what was the command used to build `.l`.

What I need is a programmatic solution, some code that given the `.l` path can return the name of the command, and I'm interested in *Tcl* solutions, or even Tcl extensions coded in C.

A way to do this could be renaming *all* the widget creation commands with procs that save that information somewhere and then does exactly what the original command would do, but this solution requires that you know all the available widget creation commands, and doesn't take into account user defined widget (or megawidgets as a whole).

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`winfo class`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/winfo.htm#M9) command will tell you the class of a widget, which is usually good enough (see this interactive session):

```
% label .tklabel;       puts [winfo class .tklabel]
Label
% ttk::label .ttklabel; puts [winfo class .ttklabel]
TLabel
```

Note that you can set the class of standard Tk toplevels and Ttk widgets at creation time. This can make things rather complex. With toplevels, you can see whether `[winfo toplevel $w] eq $w` is true, but that's not a guaranteed test from 8.5 onwards, as it is possible to reparent toplevels as children of another widget or turn classic frames into toplevels (via `wm forget`/`wm manage`).

If you *have* to get the exact command used to create a widget, the only truly sure method is to trap the creation command and log the info, like this:

```
rename frame the_real_frame
proc frame {pathName args} {
    set ::creationInfo($pathName) [list frame $args]
    the_real_frame $pathName {*}$args
}
```

It's usually easier to try to avoid such complexity (especially as in a production setting you'll also need to set things up to deal with `<Destroy>` events so that you clean up information about no-longer-extant widgets, and that just adds lots more trickiness).

Comment: And no, there's no perfect solution. Most people after this sort of thing are trying to do GUI serialization, and that's better done at a higher level, from the perspective of the application rather than the toolkit. Tk uses quite a large number of widgets internally that you probably don't want to intercept.

Comment: Thank you, Donal, precise as usual :) However, no, I'm not following the GUI serialization path. I'm just thinking about GUI programming in the large using Tcl/Tk, and ways to handle that complexity.

Comment: @Marco Well, we don't have exactly what you're looking for. In the large, I suspect it's easier to wrap classes around widgets and then memorize things at that level. For example, you remember that you popped up a window with a particular message, and not how that dialog was internally constructed or laid out.